# Ruby: How to set feedjira configuration options?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, feedzirra, feedjira

In the Feedjira 2.0 announcement blog post, it says that if you want to set the user agent, that should be a configuration option, but it is not clear how to do this. Ideally, I would like to mimic the options previously provided in Feedjira 1.0, including user_agent, if_modified_since, timeout, and ssl_verify_peer.

http://feedjira.com/blog/2014/04/14/thoughts-on-version-two-point-oh.html

With Feedjira 1.0, you could set those options by making the following call (as described [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/feedjira/feedjira/Feedjira%2FFeed.fetch_and_parse)):

```
feed_parsed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse("http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/news", {:if_modified_since => Time.now, :ssl_verify_peer => false, :timeout => 5, :user_agent => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"})
```

The only example I have seen where configuration options are set was from a [comment](https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira/pull/296#issuecomment-133862893) in a github pull request, which is as follows:

```
Feedjira::Feed.configure do |faraday|
    faraday.request :user_agent, app: "MySite", version: APP_VERSION
end
```

But when I tried something similar, I received the following error:

```
undefined method `configure' for Feedjira::Feed:Class
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[mcve]". We need to see the minimum code that demonstrates what you tried, and an explanation of why it doesn't work. Currently your question broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a patch was added to allow a timeout option to be passed to the fetch_and_parse function:
   https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira/pull/318/commits/fbdb85b622f72067683508b1d7cab66af6303297#diff-a29beef397e3d8624e10af065da09a14

However, until that is pushed live, a timeout and an open_timeout option can be passed by bypassing Feedjira for the fetching and instead using Faraday (or any library that can fetch HTTP requests, like Net::HTTP). You can also set ssl verify to false, and set the user agent, such as this:

```
require 'feedjira'
require 'pp'

url = "http://www.espn.com/espnw/rss/?sectionKey=athletes-life"

conn = Faraday.new :ssl => {:verify => false}
response = conn.get do |request|
    request.url url
    request.options.timeout = 5
    request.options.open_timeout = 5
    request.headers = {'User-Agent' => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"}
end
feed_parsed = Feedjira::Feed.parse response.body
pp feed_parsed.entries.first
```

I haven't seen a way to check for "if_modified_since", but I will update answer if I do.